# Getting the source behind clang's AST

Tags: c++, clang

Given an AST object in clang, how can I get the code behind it? I tried editing the code in the [tutorial](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/blob/master/CIBasicRecursiveASTVisitor.cpp#L37), and added:

```
clang::SourceLocation _b = d->getLocStart(), _e = d->getLocEnd();
char *b = sourceManager->getCharacterData(_b),
      e = sourceManager->getCharacterData(_E);
llvm:errs() << std::string(b, e-b) << "\n";
```

but alas, it didn't print the whole typedef declaration, only about half of it! The same phenomena happened when printing `Expr`.

How can I print and see the whole original string constituting the declaration?

Comment: I think the end source location points to the last token in the range (not one past the end) and so you'll miss the last token.

Comment: @bames53 looks like you're correct! How do I get this last token then?

Comment: Apart from the fact that it should probably be `_e` not `_w` in the third line, isn’t the difference in the last line the wrong way round? (I.e. `e - b` not `b - e`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `Lexer` module:

```
clang::SourceManager *sm;
clang::LangOptions lopt;

std::string decl2str(clang::Decl *d) {
    clang::SourceLocation b(d->getLocStart()), _e(d->getLocEnd());
    clang::SourceLocation e(clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(_e, 0, *sm, lopt));
    return std::string(sm->getCharacterData(b),
        sm->getCharacterData(e)-sm->getCharacterData(b));
}
```

Comment: That is a really good answer, but when I try to print a paragraph comment `/** ... */` using this function

`std::string fullComment2str(comments::FullComment* comment, clang::SourceManager *sm, clang::LangOptions lopt) {
    if (!comment) {
        return std::string();
    }
    clang::SourceLocation b(comment->getLocStart()), _e(comment->getLocEnd());
    clang::SourceLocation e(clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(_e, 0, *sm, lopt));
    return std::string(sm->getCharacterData(b),
        sm->getCharacterData(e)-sm->getCharacterData(b));
}`

The output doesn't contain begin+end markers.

Comment: Be warned, I did some testing with this approach, and sometimes for extremely large amounts of code, the results of `getCharacterData()` do not yield char pointers from the same buffer... I've had the "end" pointer land on the stack while the "begin" pointer pointed somewhere in the heap... This leads to the tool crashing or flooding your terminal with garbage memory.

Comment: @StevenLu Did you understand what's wrong with the methods? How can I fix it?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure that there is an easy way to do this, but I do have a stable way to fetch the FileID and offsets/line+col for the beginning and end locations (SourceManager methods), this is really plenty sufficient for my own purposes considering that Rewriter works fine. I would have to look at it some more to see how to grab the full string for large decls, reliably.

Comment: @StevenLu I had the same problem and found that @LucasWang's solution below worked flawlessly. The key seems to be using the `Lexer` to assemble the `StringRef`.

Answer (score 7):

The following code works for me.

```
std::string decl2str(clang::Decl *d, SourceManager &sm) {
    // (T, U) => "T,,"
    string text = Lexer::getSourceText(CharSourceRange::getTokenRange(d->getSourceRange()), sm, LangOptions(), 0);
    if (text.size() > 0 && (text.at(text.size()-1) == ',')) //the text can be ""
        return Lexer::getSourceText(CharSourceRange::getCharRange(d->getSourceRange()), sm, LangOptions(), 0);
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by answers' comments, all the other answers seem to have their flaws, so I'll post my own code that seems to cover all the flaws mentioned in comments.

I believe that `getSourceRange()` considers the statement as a sequence of tokens, rather than a sequence of characters. This means that, if we have a `clang::Stmt` that correpsonds to `FOO + BAR`, then the token `FOO` is at character 1, the token `+` at character 5, and the token `BAR` at character 7. `getSourceRange()` thus returns a `SourceRange` that essentially means *"This code begins with the token at 1 and ends with the token at 7"*. So we have to use `clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(stmt.getSourceRange().getEnd())` to get the actual, character-wise, location of the end character of the `BAR` token, and pass *that* as the end location to `clang::Lexer::getSourceText`. If we don't, then `clang::Lexer::getSourceText` would return `"FOO + "`, rather than `"FOO + BAR"` as we probably wanted.

I don't think my implementation has the problem @Steven Lu mentioned in the comments because this code uses the `clang::Lexer::getSourceText` function, which, [according to Clang's source documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html#a013b6a61a2f81044169446ca911a87db), is designed specifically to obtain the source text from a range.

This implementation also takes @Ramin Halavati's remarks into account ; I've tested it on some code, and it indeed returned the macro-expanded string.

Here is my implementation :

```
/**
 * Gets the portion of the code that corresponds to given SourceRange, including the
 * last token. Returns expanded macros.
 * 
 * @see get_source_text_raw()
 */
std::string get_source_text(clang::SourceRange range, const clang::SourceManager& sm) {
    clang::LangOptions lo;

    // NOTE: sm.getSpellingLoc() used in case the range corresponds to a macro/preprocessed source.
    auto start_loc = sm.getSpellingLoc(range.getBegin());
    auto last_token_loc = sm.getSpellingLoc(range.getEnd());
    auto end_loc = clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(last_token_loc, 0, sm, lo);
    auto printable_range = clang::SourceRange{start_loc, end_loc};
    return get_source_text_raw(printable_range, sm);
}

/**
 * Gets the portion of the code that corresponds to given SourceRange exactly as
 * the range is given.
 *
 * @warning The end location of the SourceRange returned by some Clang functions 
 * (such as clang::Expr::getSourceRange) might actually point to the first character
 * (the "location") of the last token of the expression, rather than the character
 * past-the-end of the expression like clang::Lexer::getSourceText expects.
 * get_source_text_raw() does not take this into account. Use get_source_text()
 * instead if you want to get the source text including the last token.
 *
 * @warning This function does not obtain the source of a macro/preprocessor expansion.
 * Use get_source_text() for that.
 */
std::string get_source_text_raw(clang::SourceRange range, const clang::SourceManager& sm) {
    return clang::Lexer::getSourceText(clang::CharSourceRange::getCharRange(range), sm, clang::LangOptions());
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to match a `ForStmt` and used `get_source_text(fs->getBody()->getSourceRange(), sm)` to get the source text of the loop body. Then I found the ending semicolon is missing if the body is a single statement (not a block). Any idea about that?

Comment: @GKxx There is a problem with statements that end in a semicolon.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320484/why-is-the-source-location-end-off-by-two-characters-for-a-statement-ending-in-a .

Answer (score 1):

Elazar's method worked for me except when a macro was involved. The following correction resolved it:

```
std::string decl2str(clang::Decl *d) {
    clang::SourceLocation b(d->getLocStart()), _e(d->getLocEnd());
    if (b.isMacroID())
        b = sm->getSpellingLoc(b);
    if (e.isMacroID())
        e = sm->getSpellingLoc(e);
    clang::SourceLocation e(clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(_e, 0, *sm, lopt));
    return std::string(sm->getCharacterData(b),
        sm->getCharacterData(e)-sm->getCharacterData(b));
}
```

Comment: I tried for Expression like lhs of the binary operator . If it contains macro  I am getting Identifier not the token . Why it is coming like that . For example I have a macro in my program ```#define abc ab int ab; int main() { abc =  0; } ``` , When I give code as input its pre-processed code clang will take. abc should be replaced to ab , when I print the string I am getting left hand side as abc . Why it is happening like that.?