# Why is the source location end off by two characters for a statement ending in a semicolon?

Tags: clang, libtooling

I'm trying to write a source to source translator using libTooling.

I'm using ASTMatchers to try to find `if` statements that don't have curly braces and then use a rewriter to add the braces.

The matcher I'm using is:

```
ifStmt(unless(hasDescendant(compoundStmt())))
```

Then I just get the start and end locations, and rewrite the curly braces.

Here's the source code for that:

```
if (const IfStmt *IfS = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::IfStmt>("ifStmt")) {
const Stmt *Then = IfS->getThen();
Rewrite.InsertText(Then->getLocStart(), "{", true, true);
Rewrite.InsertText(Then->getLocEnd(),"}",true,true);
```

Now the problem is that for some reason the end location is always off by 2 characters. Why is this so?

Comment: I tried using InsertTextAfterToken instead of InserText. It always missed the semicolon so now it's off by only one.

Comment: There is discussion of this problem on the LLVM Discourse at https://discourse.llvm.org/t/extend-stmt-with-proper-end-location/54745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general issue with the Clang AST: it usually does not record the location of the final semicolon of a statement that ends in one.  See discussion [Extend Stmt with proper end location?](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/extend-stmt-with-proper-end-location/54745) on the LLVM Discourse server.

To solve this problem, the usual approach is to start with the end location as stored in the AST, then use the [`Lexer`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html) class to advance forward until the semicolon is found.  This is not 100% reliable because there can be intervening macros and preprocessing directives, but fortunately that is uncommon for the final semicolon of a statement.

There is an example of doing this in [`clang::arcmt::trans::findSemiAfterLocation`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/ARCMigrate/Transforms.cpp#L149) in the Clang source code.  The essence is these lines:

```
  // Lex from the start of the given location.
  Lexer lexer(SM.getLocForStartOfFile(locInfo.first),
              Ctx.getLangOpts(),
              file.begin(), tokenBegin, file.end());
  Token tok;
  lexer.LexFromRawLexer(tok);
  if (tok.isNot(tok::semi)) {
    if (!IsDecl)
      return SourceLocation();
    // Declaration may be followed with other tokens; such as an __attribute,
    // before ending with a semicolon.
    return findSemiAfterLocation(tok.getLocation(), Ctx, /*IsDecl*/true);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

the SourceLocation i was getting is off by one because it only matches the token and ";" is not part of that.
btw, if anybody's wondering how to include the ";" into the range if they want to, you could just use `Lexer::MeasureTokenLength` and then add that by one and get the new `SourceLocaiton` by `offset`.

Comment: This answer assumes that the semicolon follows immediately after the preceding token, with no intervening whitespace, which is not true in general.