# Getting the token sequence from clang AST node

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I am writing a tool based on Clang libtooling that checks and warns against functions that are too similar. After obtaining a `clang::FunctionDecl`, I want to perform some similarity check on the source code.

Currently, I can get the source text following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083066/getting-the-source-behind-clangs-ast), but source-text-based similarity check is not precise enough and too slow. Is there a way of getting the source code in the form of a token sequence? It would be helpful if I can write something like this:

```cpp
SomeContainer<Token> tokens = getTokenSequence(funcDecl);
for (const auto &t : tokens)
  // ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main way that Clang Libtooling offers for getting the token sequence
is to first get the text by calling
[`clang::SourceManager::getBufferOrNone`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#af46125cf4e2e277b470d4e6877398757),
then run
[`clang::Lexer`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html)
on it to get the tokens.  This runs the lexer in "raw" mode, meaning it
does not do any preprocessing, and does not remember what happened when
preprocessing happened during parsing.

Here is a visitor function that prints the tokens of every function
definition (an excerpt of the complete program further below):

```
bool Visitor::VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *functionDecl)
{
  // Get the function start and end.  If either arises from a macro
  // expansion, get the location of that expansion, not the place in
  // the macro definition where the token was spelled.
  clang::SourceManager &sm = m_astContext.getSourceManager();
  clang::SourceLocation beginLoc = sm.getExpansionLoc(functionDecl->getBeginLoc());
  clang::SourceLocation endLoc = sm.getExpansionLoc(functionDecl->getEndLoc());

  // Print some details about the function.
  cout << functionDecl->Decl::getDeclKindName()
       << " \"" << functionDecl->getQualifiedNameAsString()
       << "\" type=\"" << typeStr(functionDecl->getType())
       << "\" at "
       << declLocStr(functionDecl)
       << ": beginLoc=" << locStr(beginLoc)
       << ", endLoc=" << locStr(endLoc)
       << "\n";

  // Get the memory buffer containing the source code.
  clang::FileID fileID = sm.getFileID(beginLoc);
  std::optional<llvm::MemoryBufferRef> buffer = sm.getBufferOrNone(fileID);
  if (!buffer) {
    // I haven't seen this happen, but might be possible when the input
    // is a serialized AST file rather than source code.
    cout << "  No buffer for this source file.\n";
    return true;
  }

  // Range of text to lex.
  char const *fileStartPtr = buffer->getBufferStart();
  char const *functionStartPtr = fileStartPtr + sm.getFileOffset(beginLoc);
  char const *functionEndPtr = fileStartPtr + sm.getFileOffset(endLoc);

  // Prepare to lex it in "raw" mode, meaning no preprocessing is done.
  clang::Lexer lexer(
    beginLoc,
    m_astContext.getLangOpts(),
    functionStartPtr,
    functionStartPtr,
    functionEndPtr);

  // Iterate over all of the tokens in the function definition range.
  // Do not rely only on the return value from 'LexFromRawLexer' to know
  // when to stop because, depending on where the end is relative to
  // tokens, it can skip over the specified end and read into unrelated
  // memory and eventually segfault (Clang bug?).
  clang::Token token;
  while (lexer.getBufferLocation() < functionEndPtr &&
         lexer.LexFromRawLexer(token /*OUT*/) == false) {
    cout << "  " << locStr(token.getLocation())
         << ": kind=" << token.getName()
         << ", len=" << token.getLength()
         << ", text: \""
         << std::string(
              fileStartPtr + sm.getFileOffset(token.getLocation()),
              token.getLength())
         << "\"\n";
  }

  return true;
}
```

When this visitor is run on the input:

```
// test.cc
// Input for print-node-tokens.cc.

// Easy case.
int f()
{
  return 2;
}

// Some macro expansions.
#define PLUS +
int g(int x)
{
  #define ECKS x
  return ECKS PLUS 4;
}

// Macro expansions at start and end.
#define INTEGER int
#define RBRACE }
INTEGER h()
{
  return 5;
RBRACE

// The entire function is inside a macro expansion.  For this
// definition, we don't get any tokens, and it's not obvious how to
// improve that.
#define IDENT(x) x
IDENT(int j() { return 6; })

// EOF
```

it prints:

```
$ ./print-node-tokens.exe test.cc
Function "f" type="int (void)" at test.cc:5:5: beginLoc=test.cc:5:1, endLoc=test.cc:8:1
  test.cc:5:1: kind=raw_identifier, len=3, text: "int"
  test.cc:5:5: kind=raw_identifier, len=1, text: "f"
  test.cc:5:6: kind=l_paren, len=1, text: "("
  test.cc:5:7: kind=r_paren, len=1, text: ")"
  test.cc:6:1: kind=l_brace, len=1, text: "{"
  test.cc:7:3: kind=raw_identifier, len=6, text: "return"
  test.cc:7:10: kind=numeric_constant, len=1, text: "2"
  test.cc:7:11: kind=semi, len=1, text: ";"
  test.cc:8:1: kind=r_brace, len=1, text: "}"
Function "g" type="int (int)" at test.cc:12:5: beginLoc=test.cc:12:1, endLoc=test.cc:16:1
  test.cc:12:1: kind=raw_identifier, len=3, text: "int"
  test.cc:12:5: kind=raw_identifier, len=1, text: "g"
  test.cc:12:6: kind=l_paren, len=1, text: "("
  test.cc:12:7: kind=raw_identifier, len=3, text: "int"
  test.cc:12:11: kind=raw_identifier, len=1, text: "x"
  test.cc:12:12: kind=r_paren, len=1, text: ")"
  test.cc:13:1: kind=l_brace, len=1, text: "{"
  test.cc:14:3: kind=hash, len=1, text: "#"
  test.cc:14:4: kind=raw_identifier, len=6, text: "define"
  test.cc:14:11: kind=raw_identifier, len=4, text: "ECKS"
  test.cc:14:16: kind=raw_identifier, len=1, text: "x"
  test.cc:15:3: kind=raw_identifier, len=6, text: "return"
  test.cc:15:10: kind=raw_identifier, len=4, text: "ECKS"
  test.cc:15:15: kind=raw_identifier, len=4, text: "PLUS"
  test.cc:15:20: kind=numeric_constant, len=1, text: "4"
  test.cc:15:21: kind=semi, len=1, text: ";"
  test.cc:16:1: kind=r_brace, len=1, text: "}"
Function "h" type="int (void)" at test.cc:21:9: beginLoc=test.cc:21:1, endLoc=test.cc:24:1
  test.cc:21:1: kind=raw_identifier, len=7, text: "INTEGER"
  test.cc:21:9: kind=raw_identifier, len=1, text: "h"
  test.cc:21:10: kind=l_paren, len=1, text: "("
  test.cc:21:11: kind=r_paren, len=1, text: ")"
  test.cc:22:1: kind=l_brace, len=1, text: "{"
  test.cc:23:3: kind=raw_identifier, len=6, text: "return"
  test.cc:23:10: kind=numeric_constant, len=1, text: "5"
  test.cc:23:11: kind=semi, len=1, text: ";"
  test.cc:24:1: kind=raw_identifier, len=6, text: "RBRACE"
Function "j" type="int (void)" at test.cc:30:1 <Spelling=test.cc:30:11>: beginLoc=test.cc:30:1, endLoc=test.cc:30:1
```

As an alternative to the "raw" lexer, if you want details about the
preprocessor actions performed during the real parse, you could use
[`clang::PPCallbacks`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html)
to hook into it while it runs.  But that seems like overkill for your
intended purpose, so I won't elaborate in this answer.

---

Complete example program:

```
// print-node-tokens.cc
// Print the tokens in an AST node.

#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"                          // clang::ASTContext
#include "clang/AST/Decl.h"                                // clang::FunctionDecl
#include "clang/AST/DeclBase.h"                            // clang::Decl
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"                 // clang::RecursiveASTVisitor
#include "clang/AST/Type.h"                                // clang::QualType
#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"                        // clang::DiagnosticsEngine
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h"                 // clang::DiagnosticOptions
#include "clang/Basic/SourceLocation.h"                    // clang::{FileID, SourceLocation}
#include "clang/Basic/SourceManager.h"                     // clang::SourceManager
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTUnit.h"                        // clang::ASTUnit
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"               // clang::CompilerInstance
#include "clang/Lex/Lexer.h"                               // clang::Lexer
#include "clang/Lex/Token.h"                               // clang::Token
#include "clang/Serialization/PCHContainerOperations.h"    // clang::PCHContainerOperations

#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBufferRef.h"                  // llvm::MemoryBufferRef

#include <iostream>                                        // std::cout
#include <optional>                                        // std::optional
#include <string>                                          // std::string

using std::cout;
using std::string;


// Visitor to print the tokens of every function definition.
class Visitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<Visitor> {
public:      // data
  clang::ASTUnit *m_astUnit;
  clang::ASTContext &m_astContext;

public:      // methods
  Visitor(clang::ASTUnit *astUnit)
    : m_astUnit(astUnit),
      m_astContext(astUnit->getASTContext())
  {}

  // Convenience methods to stringify some things.
  string locStr(clang::SourceLocation loc);
  string declLocStr(clang::Decl const *decl);
  string typeStr(clang::QualType qualType);

  // Visitor methods.
  bool VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *functionDecl);

  // Kick off the traversal.
  void traverseTU();
};

string Visitor::locStr(clang::SourceLocation loc)
{
  return loc.printToString(m_astContext.getSourceManager());
}

string Visitor::declLocStr(clang::Decl const *decl)
{
  return locStr(decl->getLocation());
}

string Visitor::typeStr(clang::QualType qualType)
{
  return qualType.getAsString();
}

bool Visitor::VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *functionDecl)
{
  // Get the function start and end.  If either arises from a macro
  // expansion, get the location of that expansion, not the place in
  // the macro definition where the token was spelled.
  clang::SourceManager &sm = m_astContext.getSourceManager();
  clang::SourceLocation beginLoc = sm.getExpansionLoc(functionDecl->getBeginLoc());
  clang::SourceLocation endLoc = sm.getExpansionLoc(functionDecl->getEndLoc());

  // Print some details about the function.
  cout << functionDecl->Decl::getDeclKindName()
       << " \"" << functionDecl->getQualifiedNameAsString()
       << "\" type=\"" << typeStr(functionDecl->getType())
       << "\" at "
       << declLocStr(functionDecl)
       << ": beginLoc=" << locStr(beginLoc)
       << ", endLoc=" << locStr(endLoc)
       << "\n";

  // Get the memory buffer containing the source code.
  clang::FileID fileID = sm.getFileID(beginLoc);
  std::optional<llvm::MemoryBufferRef> buffer = sm.getBufferOrNone(fileID);
  if (!buffer) {
    // I haven't seen this happen, but might be possible when the input
    // is a serialized AST file rather than source code.
    cout << "  No buffer for this source file.\n";
    return true;
  }

  // Range of text to lex.
  char const *fileStartPtr = buffer->getBufferStart();
  char const *functionStartPtr = fileStartPtr + sm.getFileOffset(beginLoc);
  char const *functionEndPtr = fileStartPtr + sm.getFileOffset(endLoc);

  // Prepare to lex it in "raw" mode, meaning no preprocessing is done.
  clang::Lexer lexer(
    beginLoc,
    m_astContext.getLangOpts(),
    functionStartPtr,
    functionStartPtr,
    functionEndPtr);

  // Iterate over all of the tokens in the function definition range.
  // Do not rely only on the return value from 'LexFromRawLexer' to know
  // when to stop because, depending on where the end is relative to
  // tokens, it can skip over the specified end and read into unrelated
  // memory and eventually segfault (Clang bug?).
  clang::Token token;
  while (lexer.getBufferLocation() < functionEndPtr &&
         lexer.LexFromRawLexer(token /*OUT*/) == false) {
    cout << "  " << locStr(token.getLocation())
         << ": kind=" << token.getName()
         << ", len=" << token.getLength()
         << ", text: \""
         << std::string(
              fileStartPtr + sm.getFileOffset(token.getLocation()),
              token.getLength())
         << "\"\n";
  }

  return true;
}


void Visitor::traverseTU()
{
  this->TraverseDecl(m_astContext.getTranslationUnitDecl());
}


// This is all boilerplate for a libclang program.
int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
  // Copy the arguments into a vector of char pointers since that is
  // what 'createInvocationFromCommandLine' wants.
  std::vector<char const *> commandLine;
  {
    // Path to the 'clang' binary that I am behaving like.  This path is
    // used to compute the location of compiler headers like stddef.h.
    commandLine.push_back(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR "/bin/clang");

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      commandLine.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
  }

  // Parse the command line options.
  std::shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation> compilerInvocation(
    clang::createInvocation(llvm::ArrayRef(commandLine)));
  if (!compilerInvocation) {
    // Command line parsing errors have already been printed.
    return 2;
  }

  // Boilerplate setup for 'LoadFromCompilerInvocationAction'.
  std::shared_ptr<clang::PCHContainerOperations> pchContainerOps(
    new clang::PCHContainerOperations());
  clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticsEngine> diagnosticsEngine(
    clang::CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(
      new clang::DiagnosticOptions));

  // Run the Clang parser to produce an AST.
  std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTUnit> ast(
    clang::ASTUnit::LoadFromCompilerInvocationAction(
      compilerInvocation,
      pchContainerOps,
      diagnosticsEngine));

  if (ast == nullptr ||
      diagnosticsEngine->getNumErrors() > 0) {
    // Error messages have already been printed.
    return 2;
  }

  Visitor visitor(ast.get());
  visitor.traverseTU();

  return 0;
}


// EOF
```

`Makefile`:

```
# Makefile

# Default target.
all:
.PHONY: all


# ---- Configuration ----
# Installation directory from a binary distribution.
# Has five subdirectories: bin include lib libexec share.
CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR = $(HOME)/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04

# ---- llvm-config query results ----
# Program to query the various LLVM configuration options.
LLVM_CONFIG := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/llvm-config

# C++ compiler options to ensure ABI compatibility.
LLVM_CXXFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags)

# Directory containing the clang library files, both static and dynamic.
LLVM_LIBDIR := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --libdir)

# Other flags needed for linking, whether statically or dynamically.
LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --ldflags --system-libs)


# ---- Compiler options ----
# C++ compiler.
CXX := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/clang++

# Compiler options, including preprocessor options.
CXXFLAGS =
CXXFLAGS += -g
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Werror

# Get llvm compilation flags.
CXXFLAGS += $(LLVM_CXXFLAGS)

# Tell the source code where the clang installation directory is.
CXXFLAGS += -DCLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR='"$(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)"'

# Linker options.
LDFLAGS =

LDFLAGS += -g -Wall

# Pull in clang+llvm via libclang-cpp.so, which has everything, but is
# only available as a dynamic library.
LDFLAGS += -lclang-cpp

# Arrange for the compiled binary to search the libdir for that library.
# Otherwise, one can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar before running it.
# Note: the -rpath switch does not work on Windows.
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$(LLVM_LIBDIR)

# Get the needed -L search path, plus things like -ldl.
LDFLAGS += $(LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS)


# ---- Recipes ----
# Compile a C++ source file.
%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

# Executable.
all: print-node-tokens.exe
print-node-tokens.exe: print-node-tokens.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Test.
.PHONY: check
check: print-node-tokens.exe
    ./print-node-tokens.exe test.cc

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.exe


# EOF
```